# UITableView reload all cells except one

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to reload all cells in a `UITableView` and exclude one?

I have a `MPMoviePlayerController` in each cell and because of it's Singleton-ness - When playing one - I need to invoke all the rest `initWithContentURL` to reset them.

Is it possible without iterating? (which doesn't sound much efficient)

Comment: What do you think reload does, if not iterate through the cells??

Comment: @HotLicks - so how do I do it by myself efficiently (and excluding one cell)

Comment: (Invoking an `init` method to stop play is not a very wise way to do it.)

Comment: (You might want to actually consult the documentation.)

Comment: If you bothered reading the constructive answer that was provided here instead of just bashing people seeking help, you would understand. But don't bother. Thanks for the "help"

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible without iterating.
You architecture is probably wrong. Obviously the player should not be a singleton. 
If you are working on something that is a list and each cell contains a video, than either you will have unique player instances, or you will have some thumbnails and only resort to showing the player once you want it to play something.

Comment: I have no choice with `MPMoviePlayerController`  - "Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie".

Comment: playing one, invalidates the others that played previously. That's why I want to call reload and have it ready BEHIND A THUMBNAIL for the next click

Comment: The crucial question is whether you went to have multiple videos played silently and simultaneously in the table view like Facebook app does. If yes, MPMoviePlayerController is not the right class for you. If no, then all this premature optimisation is not necessary and you simply initialise a clean instance of player once a cell is tapped and throw it away once playback finished.

Comment: The latter is the scenario, but I have a problem if the user pauses... I need to keep the player alive...

Comment: If it is paused, it is paused. Does pausing it cause it to jump back to table view?

Comment: Yeah... The user can click done and it jumps in a paused state back to the cell (a functionality I want to keep)

Comment: That is not the correct approach. Knowing where the user paused doesn't require to keep dozens of player instances. In your understanding of the problem, decouple mentally the fact of last position from the player instance. Storing some timeIndex is MUCH easier than managing a handful of player instances which all struggle for privileged position of playing something. It will make things much easier to implement.
Once it is clear the video was already partially played, you will continue to play from last know time index.

Comment: If only `MPMoviePlayerController` would let me do such a thing... It's awful but AFAIK iOS7 has no other alternative

Comment: there is property called .initialPlaybackTime from iOS 3.0 upwards which does exactly what we discussed.